# Hide dotnetnuke login username control

Tags: dotnetnuke

In dotnetnuke how can i hide the login /user name control that usually we place in a skin

I want to hide this based on some dynamic condition

I have googled and most of them say to remove it from the skin file, I dont want in this way,
Removing from skin will remove from all the pages right ?

is there any code snippet that could help me

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your condition you can include some javascript on the page to hide it, or even some CSS to display:none that HTML element.

In a skin I just looked at, it had an HTML id of dnn_userLogin_cmdLogin on the element. So with some jQuery / javascript I can.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dnn_userLogin_cmdLogin').hide();
});
</script>
```

Which will hide the login button.  Your exact needs will really depend on your skin, but you can hide the link with javascript if needed.

Answer (score 0):

DNN 7.06 supports hiding the login control for the entire portal in the site settings (or host settings, i forget which one)

If that is not your wish... you could erase the login control in your skin, and put a regular html module with a link to your login page and define with dnn permissions what role group can see this module.

otherwise what sort of "dynamic condition" do you want to set?

P.S. if you want to hide the login control on just one page, nothing could be simpler. 
Duplicate your skin (just cut paste the skin in you skin folders), erase the login control, and assign the skin to just this one or sevearal pages, leaving the Host/portal skin on the original one.

Answer (score 0):

You can see here @ DNN

it's better this or clean way with setting then the javascript way.

[Setting the Visibility of the Login Control](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/Content/Dnn.Platform/Documentation/Using%20the%20Control%20Panel/Admin%20Console/Site%20Settings/Advanced%20Settings/Security%20Settings/HideLoginControl.html)

or

Look in your skins -> there you have also a setting to hide on mobile, tablet, desktop, ...